# Отсеивание ложных значений через сравнение

Tags: php

Есть массив данных с числовыми значениями. Нужно определять среднее арифметическое, но отсеивать значения, сильно отличающиеся в большую или меньшую сторону от большинства.

Comment: Считаете мат. ожидание и дисперсию по изначальному массиву. Дальше, в зависимости от ваших критериев не сильно отличающихся от среднего, берете только те элементы массива, которые лежат в диапазоне мат. ожидание +- (1 или 2 или 3) * дисперсию. Потом считаете мат. ожидание для нового массива.

Comment: @ArchDemon Спасибо большое за ответ. Но я всё еще не могу им воспользоваться. Пример. [1, 8, 10, 12, 15]. Очевидно здесь нужно отбросить [1]. Мат. ожидание = 9,2; Дисперсия: 22,16; Диапазон при множителе 1 от +31,36 до -12,96. Уменьшил множитель до 0.3; диапазон стал от +15.84 до 4,76. [1] выпал. Но как определять этот множитель для случайных чисел?

Comment: Я думаю сделать следующим образом. Разделить среднеквадратичное отклонение на мат. ожидание и умножить на 100. Получить коэффициент вариации. Если результат будет меньше 33% тогда найти значение, которое больше других отличается от мат. ожидания и отбросить его. Повторять пока коэффициент не станет <33%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ArchDemon
Спасибо, что откликнулись.

```
function findElse ( $arrArg=[] ) 
{

$fixsion = $arrArg;

$sum = 0;
$i=0;
$koef = 100;

    foreach ($fixsion as $key => $value)
    {
        $disp += pow ($value, 2);
        $sum += $value;
        $i++;
    };

    $sum = $sum/$i;

    $disp = ($disp/$i) - pow ($sum, 2);

    $koef = ( sqrt ($disp) / $sum )*100;

    if ($koef>33) 
    {

        foreach ($fixsion as $key => $value)
        {

            if ( abs ($sum - $value)>$max)
            {
                $max = abs ($sum - $value);
                $maxId = $key;
            };
        };

        unset( $fixsion[$maxId] );
        $fixsion = array_values($fixsion);
        findElse ( $fixsion );
    };
        return $fixsion;
};
```

Comment: я вам соврал немного. Действительно дисперсия большая получается. Считать нужно не её, а среднеквадратическое отклонение (ско). И уже брать мат. ожидание +- (1 или 2 или 3) * ско